# You must add reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I download [library](http://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/)

Install it, and everything seems to be fine, but when I press `Debug`, it takes off with the error:

> Error   1   The type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' is defined in
>   an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.  Z:\RF\Программы для
>   Терминалов\TRF(FTP download) — копия\TRF\MainForm.cs    56  13  TRF

What should I do?

Here you can see, i have this library in reverence 
[image]

Comment: It isn't very clear which of the three editions of this library you downloaded.  The free version cannot be used in a .NET Compact Framework project, you must select the $199 version.  Use a telephone to get support from the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.dll and it should compile. Usually present at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll.
```

Comment: It was added before. I try to add it again, but still error.

Comment: Can you check the version of the referenced 'System.dll'?

Answer (score -1):

- Right click your project
- Click "Add"
- Click "Reference..."
- On the left menu choose "Assemblies"
- In the submenu choose "Framework"
- Scroll down to "System" and select it

Comment: Sorry, but why the down vote? I think this is the "standard" way of adding a reference to a framework assembly. I posted my answer before the screenshot was added and right in the moment the other answer was posted. It was not clear that the reference to System is already there and that it is a windows phone project :| Maybe I should delete my answer? Because now it´s that it´s not just a missing reference.